# Facebook Desktop Notifier

Tags: java, facebook, api, desktop, desktop-application

I am a beginner programmer that have never used anything other than what's included in a language.

I am trying to create a desktop application that notifies me anytime I get an update on facebook.  How should go about doing this?  Thanks in advance.

*edit*
Sorry I was not clear.  Is there any way to make a DESKTOP application with facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Facebook's developer [website](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), and start working through their "Getting Started" tutorials.

Comment: Where would I have to go from there to make desktop applications?